# Mantine Primary Color

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, colors, mantine

I want to know the Mantine primary color properties so that I can just change the primary color of all components in the theme object:

```
const theme = {
  fontFamily:
    'Inter, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif,Apple Color Emoji, Segoe UI Emoji',
  primaryColor: 'blue',
};

export default theme;
```

I only know two properties so far, that is
`var(--mantine-primary-color-filled)` and `var(--mantine-primary-color-light-hover)`.

Are there any other properties that I can find or any ways to define these?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Mantine default CSS variables are in the [CSS variables list documentation](https://mantine.dev/styles/css-variables-list/). The [CSS variables resolver](https://mantine.dev/styles/css-variables/#css-variables-resolver) utility allows you to redefine existing Mantine variables and/or define your own.

Comment: Thank you. The first link is exactly what I needed.